# How to reload different version of XenServer in my BMC in SoftLayer?

Tags: rest, operating-system, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In SoftLayer, I have a BMC with XenServer 6.2 version. I want to load XenServer 6.5.1 version. Hence, I issued reloadOperatingSystem REST API call as given below. My expectation was once it is successful, my BMC will have XenServer version 6.5.1. But it was successful per API response and BMC was not reloaded OS.

So my question is, if the JSON body is wrong, can you please give me sample JSON needed to reload different version of XenServer? or What did I do wrong in this request? or It is not possible to reload different version of XenServer in BMC from the original order? I am looking for API based programmatic solution not using portal application.

### REQUEST

POST: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/{hardwareId}/reloadOperatingSystem

### body:

```
{"token":"FORCE","config":{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Hardware_Server_Configuration","itemPrices":[{"id":164837,"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"}]}}
```

RESPONSE: Success (Http code: 200)

However, when I logged in into your portal, I am not seeing any reload os action. I expected XenServer OS version 6.5.1!!!

What did it go wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake on the way to define payload, try this please:

```
{  
    "parameters":[  
        "FORCE",
        {  
            "itemPrices":[  
                {  
                    "id":164837
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::reloadOperatingSystem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/reloadOperatingSystem)

Comment: I did try this too  `code` {"parameters":"FORCE","itemPrices":[{"id":164837,"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"}]}

Comment: I did try this too  {"parameters":["FORCE",{"itemPrices":[{"id":164837,"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"}]}]}. I will try again.

Comment: Great! anytime!