# osReloadChangeOperatingSystem.py does NOT work

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to change OS version of the Baremetal server by OS reload API.

following python code, it is suitable for my needs. then I tried this.
but it does not work. the cause of issue is very old code, API has been some changed spec.

https://gist.github.com/softlayer/407058

How do I change this code for latest API version ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following python script:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Valid Softlayer username
USERNAME = 'SET-ME'

# Valid Softlayer apiKey token, Generate one for you or your users, or 
# view yours at https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
API_KEY = 'SET-ME'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME,
                                          api_key=API_KEY)

hardwareService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']

serverId = 123456 #Change this for the BM server id.

config = {
      "itemPrices": [
                    {"id": 1857} # Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (64bit) 
                     ] 
}

try:
    """"
    reloadOperatingSystem() creates an OS reload for BM server. 
    """""
    result = hardwareService.reloadOperatingSystem('FORCE', config, id=serverId)

    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """"
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """""
    print("Unable to create an OS reload transaction, please refer to following error: "
      ". % s % s    " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

For further information you may see below (you only require to translate the REST calls to python):

[SoftLayer_Account::getOperatingSystemReloadImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563416/softlayer-accountgetoperatingsystemreloadimages)

[How to reload different version of XenServer in my BMC in SoftLayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622461/how-to-reload-different-version-of-xenserver-in-my-bmc-in-softlayer)